# C# - How can I call a variable in a method from another in the same class

Tags: c#

```
public class MathProblem
{
    public virtual void setproblem()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int num1 = random.Next(100);
        int num2 = random.Next(100);
        int sum = num1 + num2;
    }

    public virtual void askuserforanswer()
    {
        int answer;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your answer");
        answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public virtual void displayproblem()
    {

        Console.WriteLine( num1.ToString() + " + " + num2.ToString() + " = ?");

    }

}
```

I want to call **num1** and **num2** from **setproblem** method to **displayproblem** method. And I don't know how to do that.

Help please...

Comment: those are _local_ variables because they are declared inside a method. When the method exits they are destroyed and you cannot use them outside the method. To reach you functionality you need to declare them at the class global scope. Better read some [tutorial on scope in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: To make your method names more clearly I would change them to so-called CamelCasing (e.g. SetProblem, AskUserForAnswer, DisplayProblem).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Variables declared inside a method are only usable inside that method. To be able to use them throughout the class you must declare them at class level:

```
 public class MathProblem
{
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int num1, num2, sum;

    public virtual void SetProblem()
    {
        num1 = random.Next(100);
        num2 = random.Next(100);
        sum = num1 + num2;
    }

    public virtual void AskUserForAnswer()
    {
        int answer;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your answer");
        answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public virtual void DisplayProblem()
    {

        Console.WriteLine( num1.ToString() + " + " + num2.ToString() + " = ?");

    }       
}
```

Also, note I've changed the method names to Pascal casing according to Microsoft's [Capitalization Conventions.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: this time computer always give 0 to num1 and num2 always asking for 0+0

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the `SetProblem` method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fields.

```
 public class MathProblem
{
 int num1;
 int num2;

public virtual void setproblem()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    num1 = random.Next(100);
    num2 = random.Next(100);
    int sum = num1 + num2;
}

public virtual void askuserforanswer()
{
    int answer;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your answer");
    answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

public virtual void displayproblem()
{

    Console.WriteLine( num1.ToString() + " + " + num2.ToString() + " = ?");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use fields like at class level:

```
public class MathProblem
{
    int num1;
    int num2;

    ... rest of code unchanged
}
```

If you would need these outside your class you can use properties like:

```
public class MathProblem
{
    public int num1 { get; private set;}
    public int num2 { get; private set;}

    ... rest of code unchanged
}
```

Or if you want to be able to set them from outside the class:

```
public class MathProblem
{
    public int num1 { get; set;}
    public int num2 { get; set;}

    ... rest of code unchanged
}
```

Also some tips:

- if using properties use CamelCasing (e.g. Num1 instead of num1)
- also change your method names in CamelCasing (e.g. SetProblem, AskUserForAnswer, DisplayProblem).